# Compare prev_execution_date in Airflow to timestamp in BigQuery using SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to insert data from one BigQuery table to another using an Airflow DAG. I want to filter data such that the `updateDate` in my source table is greater than the previous execution date of my DAG run.

The `updateDate in my source table looks like this:` 2021-04-09T20:11:11Z`and is of STRING data type whereas`prev_execution_date`looks like this:`2021-04-10T11:00:00+00:00`which is why I am trying to convert my`updateDate` to TIMESTAMP first and then to ISO format as shown below.

```
SELECT *
FROM source_table
WHERE FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%X%Ez", TIMESTAMP(UpdateDate)) > TIMESTAMP('{{ prev_execution_date }}')
```

But I am getting the error message: `No matching signature for operator > for argument types: STRING, TIMESTAMP. Supported signature: ANY > ANY`. Clearly the left hand side of my WHERE-clause above is of type STRING. How can I convert it to TIMESTAMP or to a correct format for that matter to be able to compare to `prev_execution_date`?

I have also tried with the following:

```
WHERE FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%X%Ez", TIMESTAMP(UpdatedWhen)) > STRING('{{ prev_execution_date }}')
```

which results in the error message: `Could not cast literal "2021-04-11T11:50:31.284349+00:00" to type DATE`

I would appreciate some help regarding how to write my BigQuery SQL query to compare the String timestamp to previous execution date of Airflow DAG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you wanted to try [parse_timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp) instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM source_table
WHERE PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%X%Ez", UpdateDate) > TIMESTAMP('{{ prev_execution_date }}')
```

although looks like it will work even without it

```
SELECT *
FROM source_table
WHERE TIMESTAMP(UpdateDate) > TIMESTAMP('{{ prev_execution_date }}')
```